# The name '<NAME>' does not exist in the current context - instance across forms?

Tags: client, instance-variables

I've got an issue whereby my app has a login page which logs in and opens a new form. however, I declare the _client instance in this form and use it, but when I hide this form and open a new form, it cannot see _client. It errors and says *"The name '_client>' does not exist in the current context"*.

I can't simply call it again as it'd be a different instance, how can I use the same instance across 2 forms?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
private FutClient _client;
public login()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _client = new FutClient();
}

        public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loginDetails = new LoginDetails(email, password, secret, platform);
            try
            {
                var loginResponse = await _client.LoginAsync(loginDetails);
                this.Hide();
                abform abform = new abform();
                abform.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.textBox4.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself

called

public static FutClient _client { get; set; }

and referenced it in the next form with login._client

:-)